# How can retrieve values from Javascript variable

Tags: python-3.x

Don't know if its possible but i have written a script to download some mp3 files using python selenium which is working fine but i need to also grab some data that is stored in a javascript variable

I am trying to get "dfn=20190611-154434-123425015190- 123417133890" this data will always be changing for each download see below

```
 onclick="var response = AjaxServerSide.LogURLAccess('C','http://crc- 
 c.myphones.net:1234/cgi-bin/get-record.cgi? 
 action=audio&amp;file=record/2019/06/11/3DEC60E9-8B8E11E9-9580B8FB- 
 F6BE3F00@153.81.229.276.mp3&amp;dfn=20190611-154434-123425015190- 
 123417133890
```

I have tried this

```
download_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="dnn_ctr545_Aggregator_ctr542_CallRecordingHistory_dgCallsRecorded"]/tbody/tr[{number}]/td[7]/input[3]')
download_button.click()
data = driver.execute_script('response = AjaxServerSide.LogURLAccess')
print(data)
```

I am getting None when i print the variable, any suggestion is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a way around it by using 
val = download_button.get_attribute("onclick") to get all the attributes what i will need to do now is slice the info that i need